# Is there a way to translate a list of dna sequences into amino acids if the dna sequence is not divisible by three?

Tags: python, translation, bioinformatics

I have been struggling with turning a list of DNA sequences into amino acid sequences. The function i wrote should read the DNA list in three nucleotides. It should loop over the sequences in the list and translate each sequence, using codons in a directory. Now I know that this problem isn't exactly new and that Biopython has a translation module made for that kind of stuff. The difficulty lies in that I later want to use a degenerate codon directory, with an NNK-codon code (K being G or T) and as far as my research went there is no possibility to make custom codon dics with Biopython. Also the DNA sequences that I use aren't uniform in length.

Now I think it's time to go a little more in depth and explain where my data aka. the list of DNA sequences is coming from. The sequences (ranging from a couple 1000 to more than 1 million) are random nucleotides in between to markers that I isolated via a function using a regex search written to a text file. The structure of this file looks like this:

> CACCAGAGTGAGAATAGAAA CCAAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGCCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGTTGCGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC
> CCAAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGCCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGTTGCGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC
> CCAAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGTCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGTTGCGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC
> CCAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGCCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGTTGCGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC
> CCAAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGCCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGTTGCGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC
> CCAAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGCCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGATGCGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC
> CAGCATTAGGAGCCGGCTGATGAGAGTGAGAATAGAAA
> CCAAAAAAAAGGCTCCAAAAGGAGCCTTTAATTGTATC
> TAAACAGCTTGATACCGATAGTTGTGCCGACAATGACAACAACCATCGCCCACGCATAACCGATATATTC

What i tried is to read in the file and get a list of all sequences as strings, get rid of whitespaces and newline breaks and that kind of stuff. Start a function in which the codon usage is defined and loop over the list of sequences for each sequence in a three letter fashion, translating them to the amino acid defined by the codon in the dict.

Code I got so far:

```
input_file = 'inserts.txt'
with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    seq = f.readlines()

seq = [s.replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace("'", "").replace("\n", "") for s in seq]
print("\n".join(seq[:99]))
print("\nType lookup", type(seq))


# translation function and NNN codon table as a dict object
def translate(seq):
    nnn_table = {'TTT': 'F', 'TCT': 'S', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TGT': 'C', 'TTC': 'F', 'TCC': 'S', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TGC': 'C',
                 'TTA': 'L',
                 'TCA': 'S', 'TAA': '*', 'TGA': '*', 'TTG': 'L', 'TCG': 'S', 'TAG': '*', 'TGG': 'W', 'CTT': 'L',
                 'CCT': 'P',
                 'CAT': 'H', 'CGT': 'R', 'CTC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R', 'CTA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P',
                 'CAA': 'Q',
                 'CGA': 'R', 'CTG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R', 'ATT': 'I', 'ACT': 'T', 'AAT': 'N',
                 'AGT': 'S',
                 'ATC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S', 'ATA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R',
                 'ATG': 'M',
                 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R', 'GTT': 'V', 'GCT': 'A', 'GAT': 'D', 'GGT': 'G', 'GTC': 'V',
                 'GCC': 'A',
                 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G', 'GTA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G', 'GTG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A',
                 'GAG': 'E',
                 'GGG': 'G'}
    # two loops, outer one to loop over the list of string sequences
    # inner one loops over each sequence
    nnn_aa_seq = []
    # generate amino acid sequence
    # add option for sequence or codon not divisible by three
    print("\nStarting to translate:")
    for dna in seq:
        protein_seq = ""
        for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
            if len(dna) % 3 == 0:
                nnn_codon = nnn_table[dna[i:i + 3]]
                protein_seq += nnn_codon
            nnn_aa_seq.append(protein_seq)

    return "".join(nnn_aa_seq)


translate_nnn = translate(seq)
print(tranlate_nnn)
# do other stuff
```

Now my desired output would be a list with each amino acid sequence for each DNA sequence in the original text file.

What I get as "output" is this:

```
Starting to translate
**T*TA*TA**TA*Y*TA*YR*TA*YR**TA*YR*L*TA*YR*LR*TA*YR*LRR*TA*YR*LRRQ*TA*YR*LRRQ**TA*YR*LRRQ*Q*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQ*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQP*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQPS*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQPSP*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQPSPT*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQPSPTH*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQPSPTHN*TA*YR*
```

My guess on the problem would be that some sequences are not divisible by three. With those sequences I think it would be best to remove the overhang or have it replaced by a place holder. What do you guys think?

Edit:

All right I forgot to actually print the result and this looks nothing like i thought it would. It is one not distinguishable line of amino acids and not a list amino acid sequences for each DNA sequence. Anyhow my problem still exits. Help and any critic is welcome!

Comment: I am not familiar with this at all, but `exit code 0` usually means that the program terminanted successfully?

Comment: what happens if you add `print(translate_nnn)` at the end?

Comment: Right forgot about that, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing

```
for dna in seq:
    protein_seq = ""
    for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
        if len(dna) % 3 == 0:
            nnn_codon = nnn_table[dna[i:i + 3]]
            protein_seq += nnn_codon
        nnn_aa_seq.append(protein_seq)
```

which means you are checking if `len(dna)` is divisible by 3 many times without need to do so. `dna` length is constant inside each outer for loop run therefore you might check that before starting inner for loop and also provide clear information about that like so

```
for dna in seq:
    protein_seq = ""
    if len(dna) % 3 != 0:
        print('DNA length not divisible by 3')
        continue  # go to next element of seq
    for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):
        nnn_codon = nnn_table[dna[i:i + 3]]
        protein_seq += nnn_codon
        nnn_aa_seq.append(protein_seq)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer @Daweo! I guess normally it would be okay to have sequences that are `len(dna) % 3 != 0` to be "removed". But i think it would be best to have the overhang exchanged with a placeholder or removed. This keeps the sequence and i could still work with it. The amino acid line mentioned in my post is also still very much a thing. Interesting is it changed its composition to:`*TA*YR*LRRQ*QQPSPTHN*YIRSLRLAGS*RPLLPIVTGFTRGR**AE*E*KPKKKAPKGAFNCIPKKKAPKGAFNCIPKKKAPKGAFNCIVT*TCTRSYPERSEE*E*KSDLQSVSAEPPLA*TYPGSVSGI*KE*E*KSDLNSFRPNLHPERDRLAGGTFRVE*E*KPKKKAPKGAFNC`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish the sequences in the result, you should not `return "".join(nnn_aa_seq)`, but rather `return "\n".join(nnn_aa_seq)`, or probably better just return the whole list with `return nnn_aa_seq`.

As for the sequences not all being divisible by 3, why do you think these are protein-coding sequences at all? And if they are, is it realistic to expect your marker matching pattern to exactly capture the start of a gene? I do not see many start codons in there.

If you think these are fragments of genes, then there are three possible translations of each sequence, depending on how you align the codon frame. So you could try something like this:

```py
for dna in seq:
    protein_seq_candidates = []
    for start in (0, 1, 2):
        protein_seq = []  
        for i in range(start, len(dna), 3):
            nnn_codon = nnn_table[dna[i:i + 3]]
            protein_seq.append(nnn_codon)
        protein_seq_candidates.append(protein_seq)

    # Compare the three aa sequences in terms of biological plausibility,
    # e.g. check for stop codons within the sequences, aa distribution, etc.
    # Pick the best one (or none) and append it to nnn_aa_seq.
```

Comment: Hi @Arne and thanks for your answer! Well they should be protein-coding sequences, or better they are random insert in the pIII gene locus of M13 phage from p.h.d 12 phage library (12 being the number amino acids in the random insert) and the start codon is in the signal-sequence further upstream. Even though i am using a fuzzy regex search I think it would be fair to say that it won't always find the exact insert. I think i will add an option to specify the number of nucleotides between the markers. Even though your answer didn't satisfy my question it was still very helpful.